# Efficient Way to Recursively Multiply

Tags: python, numpy

I'm creating `N_MC` paths of simulated stock prices `S` with `n` points in each path, excluding the initial point.  The algorithm to do so is recursive on the previous value of the stock price, for a given path.  Here's what I have now:

```
import numpy as np
import time

N_MC = 1000
n = 10000

S = np.zeros((N_MC, n+1))
S0 = 1.0
S[:, 0] = S0

start_time_normals = time.clock()
Z = np.exp(np.random.normal(size=(N_MC, n)))
print "generate normals time = ", time.clock() - start_time_normals

start_time_prices = time.clock()
for i in xrange(N_MC):
    for j in xrange(1, n+1):
        S[i, j] = S[i, j-1]*Z[i, j-1]

print "pices time = ", time.clock() - start_time_prices
```

The times were:

```
generate normals time =  1.07
pices time =  9.98
```

Is there a much more efficient way to generate the arrays `S`, perhaps using Numpy's routines?  It would be nice if the normal random variables `Z` could be generated more quickly, too, but I'm not as hopeful.

Comment: `cumsum` and `cumprod` are handy functions when the ith value depends on `i-1th`.  You might be able to build your calculations from those.  Also look at the `ufunc` `accumulate` methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not necessary to loop over 'paths', because they're independent of each other. So, you can remove the outer loop `for i in xrange(N_MC)` and just operate on entire columns of `S` and `Z`.

For accelerating the recursive computation, let's just consider a single 'path'. Say `z` is vector containing the random values at each timestep (all known ahead of time). `s` is a vector that should contain the output at each timestep. `s0` is the initial output at time zero. `j` is time.

Your code defines the ouput recursively:

```
s[j] = s[j-1]*z[j-1]
```

Let's expand this:

```
s[1] = s[0]*z[0]

s[2] = s[1]*z[1]
     = s[0]*z[0]*z[1]

s[3] = s[2]*z[2]
     = s[0]*z[0]*z[1]*z[2]

s[4] = s[3]*z[3]
     = s[0]*z[0]*z[1]*z[2]*z[3]
```

Each output `s[j]` is given by `s[0]` times the product of the random values from 0 to `j-1`. You can calculate cumulative products like this using `numpy.cumprod()`, which should be much more efficient than looping:

```
s = np.concatenate(([s0], s0 * np.cumprod(z[0:-1])))
```

You can use the `axis` parameter for operating along one dimension of a matrix (e.g. for doing this in parallel across 'paths').

Comment: Thanks!  Would you please explain what you meant by using the `axis` parameter in your last line?  Are you saying that I can do this all in one line, perhaps with nested `np.concatenate`s?

Comment: Combining the first point about not needing to loop over paths, you can generalize the `cumprod()` solution to work over all rows simultaneously. This will let you generate your whole dataset in one go, working with matrices. In this case, you'd use `cumprod()`'s `axis` parameter to tell it which dimension of the matrix to multiply over.

Comment: Got it.  I actually found it faster to loop over all paths, surprisingly.